# Importing and using overlay from jquery_plugin module

Tags: 7, javascript, modal-dialogs

I am trying (and failing) to use the jquery overlay plugin from the jquery_plugin module in Drupal 7.

I am using `drupal_add_library()` to add the plugin and drupal_add_js to add the code to generate the overlays.

The overlay trigger elements are area elements within a map.

Whenever I try and trigger the overlays, I get nothing - no errors or stacktraces or alerts, or messages in Firebug.

Here is the code - added directly into the page content.

```
drupal_add_library('jquery_plugin', 'overlay');
drupal_add_js('function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(".overlayarea").overlay();
    });
}(jQuery); ','inline');
```

The map looks as the following:

```
<map name="globalmap">
    <area id="toronto" class="overlayarea" alt="Toronto" coords="94,195,6" shape="circle" rel="#tor_overlay" nohref />
    <area id="oxford" class="overlayarea" alt="Oxford" coords="576,147,6" shape="circle" rel="#oxf_overlay" nohref />
</map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the Colorbox module and the Imagemap plugin for TinyMCE. Adding `class="colorbox'` to the map area allowed me to use an overlay for that area.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this module seems to be abandoned. Using [drupal_add_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7) works only if the module used `hook_library()`. I wanted to check it in the repository of jquery_plugin, but these files aren't available. I don't know why.

If you want to use overlays, you can use directly the jQuery UI that is already included in Drupal 7.

Comment: If I remove the drupal_add_library call, Firebug informs me that overlay() is not a function (i.e. not included). Does that mean you have to include the script as suggested by @czervik?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using the jQuery plugin module; personally I simply add whatever I need to my theme.info file.

```
    scripts[] = js/jquery-tools1.42/jquery.tools.min.js
```

Then overlays are available sitewide.

Comment: I have added other js files this way with no problems. If this is the answer, what is the point of the plugin module?

Comment: The plugin module lets modules reuse a jquery plugin. If you want the overlay to be a theme-independent feature, it is very useful. Try the Libraries module for D7.